# AzCopy wait until file is uploaded before continuing

Tags: c#, command-prompt

I have made a program which backs up a Storage Account on Azure. To do this I am using AzCopy. I have 4 containers in my storage account and I do a `foreach` through my Storage account to get all containers. My first container is backed up fine however immediately after I I tell it to upload it goes to the next container in my foreach and tried uploading its contents. This causes a conflict `[WARNING] Incomplete operation with different command line detected at the journal directory.`

The "journal" is a temp file which is created by AzCopy.

I think this issue is happening because it tried to upload my second container before the first one is complete. Is there anyway to wait until all the contents in the first container have been uploaded before trying to upload the second container?

My code is as follows for my command prompt

```
var AzCopyProcess = new ProcessStartInfo
                            {
                                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                UseShellExecute = false,

                                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal

                            };

                            var process = new Process { StartInfo = AzCopyProcess };
                            process.Start();

                            process.StandardInput.WriteLine($@"cd {strCommand}");
                            Console.WriteLine("Found directory");
                            process.StandardInput.WriteLine($@"AzCopy.exe");
                            Console.WriteLine("Found exe");
                            process.StandardInput.WriteLine($"AzCopy /Source:{pslFileStore.Uri} /Dest:{dayBlob.Uri} /SourceKey:{pslFileStoreKey.ToString()} /DestKey:{pslFileStoreBackUpKey.ToString()} /S");
                            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine($"Backed up ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait till process finish. It will be enough to call this method:

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

If this solution does not work you can try the other way. Add *"\C'* at the beginning to your command. WaitForExit() is not require in this case.

```
var AzCopyProcess = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,

    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    Arguments = $"/C {strCommand}/AzCopy.exe /Source:{pslFileStore.Uri} /Dest:{dayBlob.Uri} /SourceKey:{pslFileStoreKey.ToString()} /DestKey:{pslFileStoreBackUpKey.ToString()} /S"
};

var process = new Process { StartInfo = AzCopyProcess };
process.Start();
Console.WriteLine($"Backed up ");
```

**/C** tells that we want to execute command and then exit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer however when I put in this line of code it just hung until I stopped it. Usually the container I back up takes about 2 minutes however I was waiting more than 5 and it was still hanging. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: @CraigGallagher hmm, see my edited answer. Maybe second solution will help you

Comment: It says \C is an unrecognised escape sequence

Comment: I've made that change and it says /C is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ok, I forgot to say that it should be included as a argument of *ProcessStartInfo*, see my updated answer. Modify if **strCommand** is not valid, I don't know what you have in this variable.

Comment: My strCommand is `public static string strCommand= @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy";`